# How to apply babel plugin for certain dependency?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, babel-plugin

I have write a Babel plugin for transpiling some specific dependencies.

To reduce the compiling time of babel, I want to only use it for these dependencies, my `babel.config.js` is like

```js
module.exports = {
    plugins: [["plugin-a"], ["plugin-b"]]
    // for `plugin-c` only apply to `./node_modules/certain_dependency`
```

I find [`only`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#only) is a very useful config.

Is it possible to do that on Babel?